# Select parent read access to become 'Y' when there are any any child record which has 'Y' read_access

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, case

I having trouble in  my sql query .Please see my 
example

[image]

As u see, the **inventory Report** is the parent for the **stock alert** and **stock movement report**.

Now i got a question. How can i select the parent's read access to become 'Y' when there has any child record which has 'Y' read_access? On the other hand , if there aren't any existing child record which has 'Y', the parent read_acess will become 'N'

Sorry for my bad english. Please help

Comment: Your example indicates that there may be more than one level of hierarchy in your report table. If a report and its *immediate* children have `READ_ACCESS = 'N'` and one of the *grandchildren* has a `'Y'`, do you want that `'Y'` to propagate to the grandparent?

Comment: Ya. the grandparent will be 'Y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CHILDREN_TABLE.READ_ACCESS, PARENT_TABLE.READ_ACCESS) AS READ_ACCESS
FROM TABLE AS PARENT_TABLE
    LEFT JOIN TABLE AS CHILDREN_TABLE
        ON CHILDREN_TABLE.Parent = PARENT_TABLE.Child
```

It will give you duplicates, though (2 rows for `Inventory Report`, one for `Stock Alert Report` and one for `Stock Movement Report`) You can resolve this with a `SELECT DISTINCT` ...

OR, I believe adding a GROUP BY in the children table will solve the duplicate:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CHILDREN_TABLE.READ_ACCESS, PARENT_TABLE.READ_ACCESS) AS READ_ACCESS
FROM TABLE AS PARENT_TABLE
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Parent, READ_ACCESS FROM TABLE GROUP BY Parent) AS CHILDREN_TABLE
        ON CHILDREN_TABLE.Parent = PARENT_TABLE.Child
```

Now, you will still get a duplicate if there is a child that has `READ_ACCESS` of `Y` and another that has `READ_ACCESS` of `N`. However, this sounds like something that would need to be discussed with your business rules anyway.